# CodeIgniter multiple application with subdomains and correct htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I've a question and in fact I couldn't find solution in the posts.
I'm developing a website, and it have subdomains. I want to use latest version of CodeIgniter framework. My structure is shown below:

[Structure of folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBMuV.jpg)

I put apllication folder in **admin** and **user** folder, because I want to show application_main, when url is **www.domain.com**, and show admin application, when url is **www.admin.domain.com**, and show user folder, when url is **www.user.domain.com**.
I've modified windows host file to test these on local, eveything is good work, but there is some problem:
**1**. I've created htaccess file in root and admin and user folder, to create user friendly url, and in fact, remove index.php in url.

[htaccess contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nU7hq.jpg)

But it worked just in root! When I type **www.domain.com/cotroller/method**, it worked, but **www.admin.domain.com/controller/method**, not worked! It shows **500 internal server error**. when I put index.php (**www.admin.domain.com/index.php/controller/method**), it worked. first I was resolve this, and then...
**2**. I want to just access application via subdomains. I don't want this work: **www.domain.com/admin/cotroller/method** or **www.domain.com/user/cotroller/method**, just via subdomains, like this: **www.admin.domain.com/controller/method**.
Thanks for attention, and sorry for heavy text...
any help?

Answer (score 0):

**Actually, probably wont work unless youve 2 indexes**

Quick example using vhosts you can try :

```
<virtualHost x.x.x.x:xxx>
    ServerName www.first_domain.com
    ...
    DocumentRoot path/to/this/domain_root
</VirtualHost>

<virtualHost x.x.x.x:xxx>
    ServerName www.sub_domain.com
    ...
    DocumentRoot path/to/this/domain_root
</VirtualHost
```

Comment: thanks for replying... I set virtual host before.
What's your mean about indexes?

Comment: I know what file you are saying... Its better I explain more... I have one index.php in root, and one in admin folder, and one in user folder. and I set system folder and application folder path in each one properly. Could you explain more?